# how to check image dimensions before upload in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new in laravel 4.

I want to upload photo with maximum dimensions 800x600.

Please help to guide me!

Comment: getimagesize() works here?

Comment: could you show me more?

Comment: Haha, sorry went somewhere, http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php Read this :D

Answer (score 12):

you could simple use [getImageSize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), as

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize(Input::file('file'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check validation like this

```
if ($validator->passes() && correct_size(Input::file('file'))) {
    // do something
}
```

Create a validation function like this in which ever model you choose

```
public function correct_size($photo) {
    $maxHeight = 100;
    $maxWidth = 100;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($photo);
    return ( ($width <= $maxWidth) && ($height <= $maxHeight) );
}
```

you can decide if you want to use it statically or not.  But my recommendation is not defining it statically if you would like to check other uploads using the same validation without the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Check like below in your form validation.

```
'avatar' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200'
```